# Angular property decorator function not called

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a generic table component using this [tutorial](https://morioh.com/p/ed15b895107f). I implemented the first part, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my decorator:

```
export const tableSymbol = Symbol("table");
export function Column(options: Partial<ColumnModel> = {}) {
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    if (!target[tableSymbol]) {
      target[tableSymbol] = new TableModel();
    }
    options.key = options.key || propertyKey;
    const columnOptions = new ColumnModel(options);
    target[tableSymbol].addColumn(columnOptions);
  };
}
```

and the model:

```
export class User {
  @autoserializeAs(Number)
  @Column()
  id: number;
  @autoserializeAs(String)
  @Column()
  name: string;
  @autoserializeAs(String)
  @Column()
  username: string;
}
```

and my component:

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  private _data: User[];
  private _tableModel: TableModel;
  columns: ColumnModel[];
  displayedColumns: string[];

  @Input() set data(values: any[]) { // Because AsyncPipe is used
    if (values) {
      this._data = cloneDeep(values);
      if (values.length) {
        this._tableModel = this._data[0][tableSymbol];
        this.buildColumns();
      }
    }
  }
  get data(): any[] {
    return this._data;
  }
  private buildColumns() {
    this.columns = this._tableModel.columns;
    this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(col => col.key);
  }
  constructor() {  }
  ngOnInit(): void {  }
}
```

the TableComponent is used here, in UserListComponent:

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private repository: UserRepository) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getUsers(): User[] {
    let repoUsers = this.repository.getUsers();
    return repoUsers;
  }
}

<common-table [data]="getUsers()"></common-table>
```

The repository is like this:

```
export class UserRepository {
  private users: User[] = [];
  constructor(private dataSource: RestDataSource) {
    this.dataSource.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
      this.users = <User[]> data;
    });
  }
  getUsers(): User[] {
    return this.users;
  }
}
```

And RestDataSource is like this:

```
const base_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';
export class RestDataSource {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`${base_url}users`);
  }
}
```

When I run this, it says the **tableSymbol** is undefined, which means it didn't execute the Column function. I've also uploaded my source code [here](https://gofile.io/?c=4rRhH3). Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

I'm using angular V9.1 and typescript V3.8

Comment: Can you show where and how the User objects are instantiated?

Comment: @AaronAdrian I added my repository and dataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that it was a problem in my dataSource. I had a function that was supposed to return an Observable of **User**s, but it wasn't casting the object to User. I changed it to this, and it worked like a charm.

```
export class RestDataSource {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {   }
  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${base_url}users`)
      .pipe(
        map((res: JsonArray) => DeserializeArray(res, User))
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, I found my own solution above. export const tableSymbol = Symbol.for('table'); Adding it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it with solution like below.

**tableSymbol.ts**

```
import { ColumnModel } from "./columnmodel";
import { TableModel } from "./tablemodel";
import "reflect-metadata";

export const tableSymbol = Symbol.for('table')

export function Column(options: Partial<ColumnModel> = {}) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        if (!target[tableSymbol]) {
            target[tableSymbol] = new TableModel();
        }

        options.key = options.key || propertyKey;
        const propType = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, propertyKey);
        options.propertyType = propType.name;
        const columnOptions = new ColumnModel(options);
        target[tableSymbol].addColumn(columnOptions);
    };
}
```

**DataTableComponent.ts**

```
export const tableSymbol = Symbol.for('table');

      private buildColumns() {
            const objectSymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(this._data[0]);
            this._tableModel = this._data[0][tableSymbol];
           let columns: ColumnModel[] = data as ColumnModel[];
           this.columns = columns;
           this.sortColumns();
           this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(col => col.key);
    }
```